# Identify User's Domain from Email Address

Tags: active-directory, domain

I am in an organization with multiple domains in the forest.  Most of the domains have their own email email, but a few share a common email domain.  I have a list of email address that I need to identify from which domain they are.  I have tried the PowerShell command `Get-ADUser`, but it only seems to work within my domain.  An acceptable alternative, would be to determine if users as NOT in a certain domain.

Comment: Do you use Exchange in this forest, or are you only talking about the "mail" attribute in AD?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, as AD domain structures are not my forte.  The domain I am in uses Exchange.  I think the entire forest does, but I am not positive.

Comment: Exchange operates at the forest level and keeps track globally of all email addresses, also guaranteeing their unicity; thus it's much easier to search email addresses in a multi-forest environment if Exchange is present; otherwise you have to explicitly query each domain in turn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The piece I was missing was the server parameter.  The `Get-ADUser` command is only searching in my domain.  So if I am in `my.domain.com` but I want to see if you@domain.com is the email for a user in `ur.domain.com`, I need to specify a different server like this:

```
Get-ADUser -Server "ur.domain.com" -Filter {EmailAddress -eq "you@domain.com"}
```

Edit:
This came back around so I finally built a full script to do what I need:

```
date
$da=@("a","b","c","d") #e domain not searchable
$ra=@()
$nf=@()
foreach ($u in Get-Content "C:\pathtofile\filename.txt"){
    $dh = "not found"
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $da.length -and $dh -eq "not found"; $i+=1){
        $d=$da[$i]
        if (Get-ADUser -Server $d".domain.com" -Filter {EmailAddress -eq $u}){
            $dh = $d
        }
    }
    if ($dh -eq "not found"){
        $nf += $u
    }elseif (!($ra.Contains($dh))){
        $ra += $dh
    }
}
date
""
"Results:"
$ra
""
"Not Found:"
$nf
```

This script takes a VERY long time, so I also sorted the `$da` array by most the expectation of most frequent occurrences so it will exit that loop faster.

Answer (score 0):

This PowerShell cmdlet searches for users with the email address you specify. It also returns use accounts for which it is a secondary email address:

```perl
Get-ADUser -Filter "proxyAddresses -like '*jon.doe@example.com*'" # Keep the asterisks!
```

If you do not have Exchange in your organisation, you can also try with the mail attribute.

```perl
Get-ADUser -Filter "mail -like 'jon.doe@example.com'" # Exact search, so no asterisk here.
```